# ensure atleast one check box is selected in Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have 12 check boxes and I am trying to validate if at least one check box is selected.I am maintaining an old Flex 3 application. Does anyone have an idea how I could do this in Flex 3?

Thanks
KS

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing it would be:

`var atLeastOne:Boolean = chk01.selected || chk02.selected || ... || chk12.selected;`

Of course, you would need to fill in the `...` with checks for `chk03` through `chk11`.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below link to use required validator for checkbox
http://hugolarcher.com/2011/03/18/validate-checkbox-in-flex/